# Don't they see, what they do to me?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

I'm the essence of every living being
But humans seem to not understand
Even though others are always fleeing
They keep using for their demand

Soon I will just watch from above
How evil and innocent sink to the ground
Finally gone with the hate and love
They don't see, nobody will be crowned

> Do you know, who is your everyday fellow?

Hint:

> I'm a big part of the environment humans destroy
>  Even though I provide so much for their survival
>  They won't stop, the using they just too much enjoy
>  Soon I'm gone and it will be too late for a revival

Answer (score 2):

If we look at this riddle as an acrostic we get

> IBETSHFT, i.e. I bet SHFT. It might be related to https://www.shft.com/about/, so we are talking about the environment.

I'm the essence of every living being
But human seem to not understand
Even though others are always fleeing
They keep using for their demand

> We are using all the things around us but we seem not to care

Soon I will just watch from above
How evil and innocent sink to the ground
Finally gone with the hate and love
They don't see, nobody will be crowned

> And when in the end we've destroyed the one that lets us live, there still be some environment to watch us from 'above' (because everybody will end up 6 ft under).
>  SHFT is an organisation that tries to raise concert about the protection of the environment.

Comment: Nice try and pretty close but incorrect.

Comment: @Nati How about a hint then?

Answer (score 2):

You are..

> carbon

I'm the essence of every living being

> In our corner of the universe, all organisms are **carbon-based** life forms.

But humans seem to not understand
Even though others are always fleeing
They keep using for their demand

> The unsustainable burning of fossil fuels to meet civilization's **energy demands** are causing extreme weather patterns which produce **climate refugees**.

Soon I will just watch from above

> The combustion of fossil fuels releases carbon dioxide **into the atmosphere**.

How evil and innocent sink to the ground

> The effects of climate change does not discriminate between polluters and tree huggers. The "sink" part could reference the **rising sea levels** due to melting polar ice.

Finally gone with the hate and love
They don't see, nobody will be crowned

> In the end, **no one wins** in a world ravaged by climate change. Except fish. They'll probably be okay.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are

> **The sun**

*I'm the essence of every living being*

> Sunlight powers photosynthesis, which is the primary source of energy for most food chains

*But humans seem to not understand*
*Even though others are always fleeing*

> Nocturnal animals, such as owls, "flee" the sun by sleeping during daytime and waking during the night. Humans, on the other hand, are diurnal.

*They keep using for their demand*

> Humans have harnessed the sun as the source of energy for solar power

*Soon I will just watch from above*

> The sun is in the sky

*How evil and innocent sink to the ground*
*Finally gone with the hate and love*
*They don't see, nobody will be crowned*

> The sun will outlive humans with about 5 billion years left to live, compared to ~122 years for the longest confirmed human lifespan.

Answer (score 0):

My fellow can be:

> water

reasoning:

> cells are water based, humans deplet freshwater sources while climate change increases vapor in air,that induces heavy rainfalls, that causes sinking, the freshwater reservoirs however will not refill, animals flee away from flooding water or flee from dry places towards fresh water sources in search for water. (Maybe the "crowning" refers to "aqua regia")

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> a stuffed trophy of an endangered species.

I'm the essence of every living being

> All life will cease to exist someday. So, everything living is endangered.

But humans seem to not understand

> we stand above every other species, or feel that we are better.

Even though others are always fleeing

> fleeing from the hunters, or leaving, going extinct.

They keep using for their demand

> demand for trophies on the wall

Soon I will just watch from above

> a stuffed trophy head hanging on the wall

How evil and innocent sink to the ground
Finally gone with the hate and love

> will outlast non-taxidermed things

They don't see, nobody will be crowned

> Nobody will be crowned the winner when we are all gone.